# Number Found Accuracy on Search API Affecting Cursor Results

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search, google-search-api

When using the google app engine search API, if we have a query that returns a large result set (>1000), and need to iterate using the cursor to collect the entire result set, we are getting indeterminate results for the documents returned if the number_found_accuracy is lower than our result size.

In other words, the same query ran twice, collecting all the documents via cursors, does not return the same documents, UNLESS our number_found_accuracy is higher than the result size (ex, using the 10000 max).  Only then do we always get the same documents.

Our understanding of how the number_found_accuracy is supposed to work is that it would only affect the number_found estimation. We assumed that if you use the cursor to get all the results, you would be able to get the same results as if you had run one large query.

Are we mis-understanding the use of the number_found_accuracy or cursors, or have we found a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of number_found_accuracy is correct. I think that the behavior you're observing is the surprising interplay between replicated query failover and how queries that specify number_found_accuracy affect future queries using continuation tokens.

When you index documents using the Search API, we store them in several distinct replicas using the same mechanism as the High Replication Datastore (i.e., [Megastore](http://www.cidrdb.org/cidr2011/Papers/CIDR11_Paper32.pdf)). How quickly those documents become live on each replica depends on many factors. It's usually immediate, but the delay can become much longer if you're doing batch writes to a single (index, namespace) pair.

Searches can get executed on any of these replicas. We'll even potentially run a search that uses a continuation token on a different replica than the original search. If the original replica and/or continuation replica are catching up on their indexing work, they might have different sets of live documents. It will become consistent "eventually" but it's not always immediate.

If you specify number_found_accuracy on a query, we have to run most of the query as if we're going to return number_found_accuracy results. We specifically have to read much further down the posting lists to find and count matching documents. Reading a posting list results in its associated file block being inserted into various caches.

In turn, when you do the search using a cursor we'll be able to read the document for real much more quickly *on the same replica* that we'd used for the original search. You're thus less likely to have the continuation search failover to a different replica that might not have finished indexing the same set of documents. I think that the inconsistent results you've observed are the result of this kind of continuation query failover.

In summary, setting number_found_accuracy to something large effectively prewarms that replica's cache. It will thus almost certainly be the fastest replica for a continuation search. In the face of replicas that are trying to catch up on indexing, that will give the appearance that number_found_accuracy has a direct effect on the consistency of results, but in reality it's just a side-effect.